# How to check if build parameter is available in Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a pipeline script that should work with and without parameters. So I have to check if the parameter is available.

I tried `if(getBinding().hasVariable("myparameter"))` but this leads to an Exception

```
org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.RejectedAccessException: Scripts not permitted to use method groovy.lang.Binding getVariables
```

Is there another way to check if the job is parameterized?

Comment: In Jenkins ver. 2.131, it is always giving me false. whether the parameter exist or not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Newer versions make the parameters available through the `params` variable. If the parameter is not defined, it falls back to the configured default (see also [here](https://st-g.de/2016/12/parametrized-jenkins-pipelines)).

Answer (score 19):

This is how I did that:

```
def myParam = false
if (params.myParam != null){
    myParam = params.myParam
}
```

Why do that at all when you can just define parameters in your pipeline as suggested above?

Well, there are situations when you want your pipeline file to work regardless of if parameter is defined or not. I.e., if you're re-using your pipeline script from different Jenkins jobs and you don't want to *make* people define that parameter ...

Answer (score 11):

In the latest version of jenkins `println(getBinding().hasVariable("myparameter"))` is permitted and does not give an error any more.

Comment: Can you please update with which version was the latest version at your time of writing?

Comment: Did not work with Jenkins 2.263.1 (2020-12-03). params (as in the other answers) worked.

Answer (score 6):

See [Getting Started with Pipeline, Build Parameters](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/#build-parameters):

> #### Build Parameters
>
> If you configured your pipeline to accept parameters using the **Build with Parameters** option, those parameters are accessible as Groovy variables of the same name.

**UPDATE**

- ☑*This build is parameterized* → <kbd>Add parameter</kbd> → *String Parameter*:

  - *Name*: `STRING_PARAMETER`
  - *Default Value*: `STRING_PARAMETER_VALUE`
- ***Pipeline*** → *Definition*: `Pipeline script` → *Script*:

```groovy
def stringParameterExists = true
def otherParameterExists = true

try {
  println "  STRING_PARAMETER=$STRING_PARAMETER"
  }
catch (MissingPropertyException e) {
  stringParameterExists = false
  }  

try {
  println "  NOT_EXISTING_PARAMETER=$NOT_EXISTING_PARAMETER"
  }
catch (MissingPropertyException e) {
  otherParameterExists = false
  }

println "  stringParameterExists=$stringParameterExists"
println "  otherParameterExists=$otherParameterExists"
```

Console Output:

```
[Pipeline] echo
  STRING_PARAMETER=STRING_PARAMETER_VALUE
[Pipeline] echo
  stringParameterExists=true
[Pipeline] echo
  otherParameterExists=false
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Comment: No. "echo myparameter" or "if(myparameter != null)" fail with "groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: myparameter for class: groovy.lang.Binding"

Comment: @domruf You're right. I apparently confused something. See the update to my answer.

Comment: I found out that you can add method calls to a whitelist with https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Script+Security+Plugin. But that requires admin privileges.

Answer (score 1):

**The problem**: Avoiding null parameters or not configured one's in your pipeline job

**Solution**: You've got 2 options in order to set default configuration to variables in declarative pipelines

**Option 1**. Using jenkins ability to set parameters scope fallback , this affect your pipeline configuration on job in jenkins (if your configure things in your declarative pipeline it will override your configuration in job parameters).

```
parameters{    
  booleanParam(defaultValue: false, description: 'some description', name: 'SOME_FLAG')
}
```

**Option 2**. **Securing your variables yourself**, check if variable is not null and then assign the variable in the pipeline , this functionality doesn't affect your job configuration and it's better in my opinion:

```
some_flag = params.SOME_FLAG != null ? params.SOME_FLAG.toBoolean() : false
```